# Splitting a list of tuples by 2nd element - python

Tags: python, filter, tuples, list-comprehension

How can i split a list of tuples by the 2nd element?

I can do it with 2 list comprehension:

```
tup = [('x',1),('y',2),('z',1)]

ones = [i for i in tup if i[1] == 1]
twos = [i for i in tup if i[1] == 2]
```

but is there a way to avoid looping through the list twice? like this?

```
ones, twos = [], []

for i in tup:
  if i[1] == 1:
    ones.append(i)
  if i[1] == 2:
    twos.append(i)
```

any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

numbered = defaultdict(list)
for i in tup:
    numbered[i[1]].append(i)
```

Now `numbered[1]` contains all ones, `numbered[2]` a list of all twos. This solution extends to more values of `i[1]` naturally without having to define any additional lists or `if` statements.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> tup = [('x',1),('y',2),('z',1)]
>>> numbered = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in tup:
...     numbered[i[1]].append(i)
... 
>>> numbered
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [('x', 1), ('z', 1)], 2: [('y', 2)]})
>>> numbered[1]
[('x', 1), ('z', 1)]
>>> numbered[2]
[('y', 2)]
```

A `defaultdict` is just a `dict` subclass with additional behaviour; you can do without it too with a little more complexity and a slight loss in speed:

```
numbered = {}
for i in tup:
    numbered.setdefault(i[1], []).append(i)
```